# Covering the disk with a family of infinite total measure

Tags: measure-theory, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry, problem-solving

Let $(U_n)_n$ be an arbitrary sequence of open subsets of the unit disk $D(0,1)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda(U_n)=\infty$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure). **Does there exist a sequence $(q_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $D(0,1) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty (q_n+U_n)$?**

With the notation $q_n+U_n$, I mean
$$q_n+U_n:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2|x-q_n\in U_n\}$$

EDIT: Fedor Petrov was quick to find an easy answer to this one and I'm forced to accept it. His method doesn't hold up though if I additionally demand that all the $U_n$ are convex. So, submissions with a take on such a related question are still welcome (although I'll not be able to reward your submission with a "accepted answer" badge)

UPDATE: Acting on popular request, I've reposted the revised question [over here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345706/covering-the-disk-with-a-family-of-infinite-total-measure-the-convex-sequel).

Comment: It looks reasonable to ask a separate question for convex sets.

Comment: By Fritz John's theorem, the question involving convex sets is the same as requiring that all of the $U_n$ be open ellipses (or rectangular boxes - not necessarily coordinate aligned)

Comment: . . . and then you can assume for each $\epsilon \gt 0$
that they're aligned within $\epsilon$ if that helps.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: there is now another question circulating https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345706/covering-the-disk-with-a-family-of-total-measure-the-convex-sequel

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No even in dimension 1 (and multiplying the example for $\mathbb{R}$ by the small segment you get a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Take the set $A_n\subset \mathbb{R}$ defined as $\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} (2k\cdot 10^{-n},(2k+1)\cdot 10^{-n})$. I claim that there exists no finite family of translates $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_n+q_n)$ which covers $[0,1]$. Indeed, we may recursively find a nested family segments $[0,1]\supset \Delta_1\supset \Delta_2\ldots$ such that length of $\Delta_i$ equals $10^{-i}$ and $\Delta_i\cap (A_i+q_i)=\emptyset$. The intersection of $\Delta_i$'s is not covered by our translates.

Now if $U_n=[0,1]\cap A_n$, the measures of $U_n$ are bounded from below.